# pretty printing JSON with padding in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a set of JSON key/values to a file with both pretty-print as well as padding like so:

```
{
   "k1DaySummary"               : "1 day summary",
   "k1HourSummary"              : "1 hour summary",
   "k1MonthSummary"             : "1 month summary",
   "k1WeekSummary"              : "1 week summary",
   "kAlarmAPIError"             : "error - please make sure your API supports this feature",
   "kAlarmFrameCount"           : "Alarm Frame Count",
   "kAlarmMaxFPS"               : "Alarm Max FPS",
   "kAlarms"                    : "Alarms",
   "kAnalyze"                   : "Analyze",
   "kApiUrl"                    : "api url",
   "kApplyingChanges"           : "Applying changes. Please wait",
   "kArrangingImages"           : "arranging images",
   "kAt"                        : "at",
   "kAuthSuccess"               : "authentication success",
   "kAuthenticating"            : "authenticating",
   "kAwake1"                    : "Keep display on",
   "kAwake2"                    : "(when viewing footage)",
   "kBannerAPICheckFailed"      : "API check failed",
   "kBannerCannotDeleteNeedOne" : "Cannot delete, need at least one"
}
```

I am currently using `json.dumps` the following way (f=filename, k=set of keys)

```
#beautifies a given file
def beautify(f,k):
  print "Beautifying ",f
  pFh=open  ('pretty-'+f,"w")
  pFh.write(json.dumps(k,indent=4,sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False))
  pFh.close()
```

This does not pad the value column. The only solution I can think of is to not use `json_dumps` and instead use python string formatting, calculate the length of the longest key (mK) and then iterate through the array pretty printing each key with `

This is the alternate approach:

```
#beautifies a given file
def beautify(fi,ki):
  print "Beautifying ",fi
  w = len (max(ki, key=len))
  pretty=[]
  for k,v in ki.iteritems():
    line = "    \"%s\"%s:\"%s\"" %(k,' '*(w-len(k)+1),v)
    pretty.append(line)
  pFh=open  ('pretty-'+fi,"w")
  pFh.write("{\n")
  pFh.write(',\n'.join(pretty))
  pFh.write("\n}\n")
  pFh.close()
```

Is there are more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I think string formatting is the only way to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks Marcus - I'm new to Python - I edited my post to reflect the non json dump format - any better ways?

Comment: `line = "    {k!r:<{w}s}:{v!r}".format(k=k, w=w, v=v)` would be better in my opinion but it isn't a huge improvement.

Comment: `.format` is always better than `%`'s, +1

Answer (score 0):

This version prints to stdout, which you can redirect into your new file:

```
import json

w = 0
pairs = []        # holds the formatted data
for k,v in ki.iteritems():
    k = json.dumps(k)
    v = json.dumps(v) + ","
    pairs.append((k, v))
    w = max(w, len(k))    # find the widest key value, after formatting

print '{'
for k,v in pairs:
    print '   ', k.ljust(w), ':', v
print '}'
```

It preserves any formatting by using `json.dumps()` and pads the left column using `ljust()`.

[Edited to find max width after data formatting]

Comment: Thanks - though since we are anyway iterating each k,v, the only benefit of json.dumps  seems to be adding quotes - wouldn't it be simpler and faster to just add quotes and not use json.dumps twice while iterating?

Comment: If a string contains a special character, `json.dumps()` will include the slash, for example `\"`

Comment: Edited to pre-process the data and get the width after formatting